# Automate add-in installation when installing an app

Tags: c#, node.js, vsto, powerpoint

Good day everyone,
I developed a desktop app in electron nodeJS and also an add-in to work with it in Microsoft PowerPoint. so what am searching for is a way for me to make my app install the add-in into Microsoft PowerPoint while it is been installed.
In case you know how to solve this issue in `java` or `c#`, your answer is also welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Your app will need to do two things, assuming that a copy of the add-in file (PPA or PPAM) is already on the user's computer:

1) Make sure PPT isn't running (or ask the user to do that).

2) Make two registry settings for each version of PPT you want to install the add-in into. It won't hurt to add the settings for multiple versions.

Here's an example set of reg entries that my installer makes for one of my addins:

First, a new KEY for the add-in. Substitute the correct version number for XX:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\XX.0\PowerPoint\AddIns\RESIZE

Then under that key, two new VALUES:

```
Path, a REG_SZ containing the path to your add-in file
AutoLoad, a REG_DWORD = ffffffff hex
```

As to the version number, PPT 2016 = 16.0, 2013 = 15.0, 2010 = 14.0, 2007 = 12.0 (even MS is a bit superstitious, it seems!), 2003 = 11.0 and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will make this an answer as soon as i try it out